# Get column values from a Haskell Database

Tags: database, list, haskell, pattern-matching

Here's the problem. Let it be known that I'm very new to Haskell and the declarative language part is totally different from what I'm used to. I've made a database of sorts, and the user can input commands like "Add (User *"Name"*)" or "Create (Table "Funding")". I'm trying to create a function that takes as parameters a list of commands, a User, a Table, a Column name (as a string), and returns a list containing the values in that column if the user has access to them (i.e. somewhere in the list of commands there is one that matches "Allow (User *name*) (Table "Funds")". We can assume the table exists.

```
    module Database where

type Column = String
data User = User String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Table = Table String deriving (Eq, Show)
data Command =
    Add User
  | Create Table
  | Allow (User, Table)
  | Insert (Table, [(Column, Integer)])
  deriving (Eq, Show)


-- Useful function for retrieving a value from a list
-- of (label, value) pairs.

lookup' :: Column -> [(Column, Integer)] -> Integer
lookup' c' ((c,i):cvs) = if c == c' then i else lookup' c' cvs

lookupColumn :: [(Column, Integer)] -> [Integer]
lookupColumn ((c, i):cvs) = if null cvs then [i] else [i] ++ lookupColumn cvs 

select :: [Command] -> User -> Table -> Column -> Maybe [Integer]
select a b c d = if not (elem (b, c) [(g, h) | Allow (g, h) <- a])
  then Nothing
  else Just (lookupColumn [(d, x) | Insert (c, [ (d, x ), _ ]) <- a])
```

I have gotten it to work, but only in very select cases. Right now, the format of the input has to be such that the column we want the values from must be the first column in the table. Example input is below. Running: `select example (User "Alice") (Table "Revenue") "Day"` returns `Just [1,2,3]` like it should, but replacing `Day` with `Amount` doesn't work.

```
example = [
    Add (User "Alice"),
    Add (User "Bob"),
    Create (Table "Revenue"),
    Insert (Table "Revenue", [("Day", 1), ("Amount", 2400)]),
    Insert (Table "Revenue", [("Day", 2), ("Amount", 1700)]),
    Insert (Table "Revenue", [("Day", 3), ("Amount", 3100)]),
    Allow (User "Alice", Table "Revenue")
  ]
```

A bit of explanation about the functions. `select` is the function which should return the list of integers in that column. Right now, it's only matching the first column, but I'd like it to work with any number of columns, not knowing which column the user wants ahead of time.

`[(d, x) | Insert (c, [ (d, x ), _ ]) <- a]` returns a list of tuples that match only the first tuple in each list of (Column, Integer) tuples.

`lookupColumn` takes in a list of tuples and returns a list of the integers within it. Unlike `lookup'`, we know that the list this takes in has only the correct column's (Column, Integer) tuples within it. `lookup'` can take in a list of any number of tuples, but must check if the column names match first.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your datatype is good for writing commands in a "natural" way, but not easy for doing the type of things you are doing. I would suggest first writing an "eval" or "run" function, which has the type `eval :: [Command] -> ([(Table, [(Column, Integer)])], [(User, Table)]`, where the first element of the tuple is the list of tables with their contents, and the 2nd is the relation "allowed" (ie, which users are allowed which database). Of course, you can (and probably should) define your own datatypes for those. Once you have that, your problem becomes quite trivial.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple strange things in your code; for example:

```
 lookupColumn :: [(Column, Integer)] -> [Integer]
 lookupColumn ((c, i):cvs) = if null cvs then [i] else [i] ++ lookupColumn cvs
```

is much longer to type in every way than the equivalent (and probably faster) `map snd`.

Furthermore when you're defining your own data structures often tuples are superfluous; you could just write:

```
data Command = Add User
             | Create Table
             | Allow User Table
             | Insert Table [(Column, Integer)]
                    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The *actual* problem is the `_` in your `select` statement which explicitly tells Haskell to throw away the second value of the tuple. Instead you want something which grabs all `(Column, Integer)` pairs that are associated with a table:

```
getCells :: [Command] -> Table -> [(Column, Integer)]
getCells db t = concat [cis | Insert t' cis <- filter isInsert db, t == t']
    where isInsert (Insert _ _) = True
          isInsert _ = False
```

(note that this is using the un-tupled version of `Insert` that I wrote above). With this the algorithm becomes much easier:

```
select :: [Command] -> User -> Table -> Column -> Maybe [Integer]
select db user table col
   | Allow user table `elem` db = Just [i | (c, i) <- getCells db t, col == c]
   | otherwise = Nothing
```

What's doing the majority of the "work" here? Actually it's just the `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` that we used in `getCells`. By concatenating together all of the `(Column, Integer)` pairs for all of the rows/cols in the table, we have a really easy time of pulling out only the column that we need.

Todo: stop this code from doing something unexpected when someone says `Insert (Table "Revenue") [("Amount", 1), ("Amount", 2400)]`, which will appear in the output as two rows even though it only comes from one row. You can either normalize-on-input, which will do pretty well, or return `[Maybe Integer]`, giving nulls for the rows which do not have a value (`lookup` in the standard Prelude will take the place of `concat` in doing your work for you).